# Using CellNav + Edit causes grid to steal focus from inputs outside of grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have an application that uses ui-grid with cellNav and edit with editOnFocus=true for some columns.  The problem I have is that the END_CELL_EDIT and CANCEL_CELL_EDIT in the edit feature always call gridCtrl.focus().  If I have an editable cell focused and then click on an input outside of the grid it will steal the focus and put it back in the grid.

What happens is I click in the input outside of the grid.  It receives focus.  At the same time the END_CELL_EDIT event is triggered.  This then calls the gridCtrl.focus() and the focus is taken away from the outside input box.

Is there a way to override this behavior in ui-grid.edit?  Why is this behavior standard?

Here is a plnkr to demonstrate.  If you click on the age column to make it enter edit mode and then click on the text area you will see it momentarily gains focus and has a cursor but then quickly the grid steals the focus back and you can no longer edit.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sg1dTcsMN0zNRDmauwoT
 
This behavior is not ideal for my situation because we are automatically focusing on a particular cell (entering edit mode) whenever the row is selected or navigated to.  So any action that changes row or moves the focus outside of the grid triggers the END_CELL_EDIT event and the focus behavior described above.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is setting up another focus, but delaying it by a digest cycle - thus allowing the grid to do what it needs to.  Relevant code snip-its from your updated Plunker below.

HTML (for binding):

```
<textarea id="textarea" ng-focus="delayFocus()"></textarea>
```

Controller (to allow digest cycle):

```
$scope.delayFocus = function() {
  $timeout(function() {
    focus('textarea');
    $scope.gridApi.grid.cellNav.clearFocus();
  });
}
```

Factory (to use for re-focus):

```
app.factory('focus', function($timeout, $window) {
  return function(id) {
    // timeout makes sure that it is invoked after any other event has been triggered.
    // e.g. click events that need to run before the focus or
    // inputs elements that are in a disabled state but are enabled when those events
    // are triggered.
    $timeout(function() {
      var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
      if (element)
        element.focus();
    });
  };
});
```

Updated Plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/UX8tbVwi9gG4zsMRG0kV?p=preview.

You could probably combine the above into one directive and then just apply it to the controls needed - happy to help, if desired/needed.

Hopefully, that'll get you off to a good start.

Comment: I was able to come up with essentially the same as above.  Though there is one major outage for our use case.  When you refocus on the textarea the editable field exits the edit state but the underlying cell is still "focused" by ui-grid.
This means that clicking on the row or the cell will not enter the edit state.  You can switch rows to enter the edit state on a new row but if you only have one row this is not an option.  You can also double click to regain focus however we have a double-click listener on the row that opens a new page.

Comment: I added a `$scope.gridApi.grid.cellNav.clearFocus();` when re-focusing on the 'textarea', and updated the Plunker, does that help?